# Not Able to Add Migrations in .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I keep getting this message every time I try to add a migration. I'm using N-Layer architecture and it always points at my API and not my context class library as i set it in my package manager console

> Your startup project 'API' doesn't reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design. This package is required for the Entity Framework Core Tools to work. Ensure your startup project is correct, install the package, and try again.

Note that I'm using EF Core Design package in my context class library and I referenced it in my API project.

Comment: Did you choose the appropriate solution project from the `Default project:` drop-down of the `Package Manager Console` window?, i.e. the one where your `DbContext` class is located?

Comment: @StefanWuebbe Yes, that's what i exactly did!